# mysql query homework

Tags: mysql, sql, select

## 6 What is the most popular male and female names from your birth year?

The database is of BabyNames with attributes:
name, year, gender, place and count.

```
select sum(count) 
from BabyName 
where year='1989';
```

Returns the total count from the year 1989

```
select name, sum(count) 
from BabyName 
where year=1989 
group by name;
```

Returns a full list of the total counts for each name from the year 1989

How can I add onto query so that it will return the Name
with the highest count for this specific year of both gender='M' and gender='F'.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  One reasonable solution uses `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Maybe creating a temporary table could help solve your problem as well

Comment: Very sorry to some of the comments, but count is an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

It really takes two queries, one for each gender, and limiting each to the first row when sorted by count:

```
(select 
    `name`,
    `gender`,
    count(*) as `num_found`
FROM BabyName 
WHERE `year` = '1989' AND `gender` = 'M'
GROUP BY `name`,`gender`
ORDER BY `num_found` DESC
LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(select 
    `name`,
    `gender`,
    count(*) as `num_found`
FROM BabyName 
WHERE `year` = '1989' AND `gender` = 'F'
GROUP BY `name`,`gender`
ORDER BY `num_found` DESC
LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you want to display the result with the highest count only. In that case you have to use the method TOP, ROWNUM or LIMIT depends on what database you're working with.
The TOP works like that: SELECT TOP /number/ , in your case SELECT TOP 1 name, sum(count)
If the LIMIT works then you put it as the last line in the query: LIMIT 1
If the ROWNUM works then you use it like that: WHERE ROWNUM <=1

Update: since your databse is MySQL you should use LIMIT

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you want to get two row in result. One is for max count male name and one is for max count female name.

I have created following sample database.

[image]

Now you want output as

[image]

Try with Following Code

```
(SELECT name,SUM(count) 
from BabyName
 where gender='F' and year='1989'
group by name 
having SUM(count) = (select MAX(name_count)  
   from (select SUM(count)  name_count 
     from BabyName
         where gender='F' and year='1989'
     group by name ) tab))
     UNION ALL
     (
     SELECT name,SUM(count) 
from BabyName
         where gender='M' and year='1989'
group by name 
having SUM(count) = (select MAX(name_count)  
   from (select SUM(count)  name_count 
     from BabyName
         where gender='M' and year='1989'
     group by name ) tab)

     )
```